# Find nested objects and store in a variable

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I'm working with TomTom Maps and I need to get all the markers that are displaying on the map.

I got all the information but the problem is when they cluster the markers.

I have the following schema:

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVK39.png)

For every element, I can have a ***marker***, which is the info that I need to store. An I can have the ***_childClusters*** that contains the same element.

How can I loop through this gettin all the markers even if it's very deep?

Thank you guys!

**Edit:**

Based in @thedude code, I made a function that returns me an array of all the pins:

```js
var markerList = new Array();

        function getMarkers(featureBounds) {
            featureBounds.map(o => {
                // console.log('o :', o);
                if (o._childCount) {
                    getMarkers(o._childClusters)
                } 
                o._markers.map(marker => {
                    // console.log('marker :', marker);
                    if (marker.propData) {
                        markerList.push(marker)
                    }
                })
            })

        }
        
        getMarkers(featureBounds)
        console.log('markerList :', markerList);
```

Comment: can the objects inside `_childClusters` have `_childClusters` of their own?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to do this, or for an efficient way to do this. Because I can't think of an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Yes, it can have _childClusters. The objects that are inside the _childClusters and _markers has the same properties as the 'mother element'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not super efficient but very "functional", assuming `data` contains the data in your question:

```
data.flatMap(o => o._markers)
    .concat(
         data.flatMap(o => o. _childClusters)
             .filter(Boolean)
             .flatMap(o => o._markers)
    )
```

This works in Chrome as is, you might need to use something like [flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flatMap) for other browsers

-- edit --

In case of deeper `_childClusters` you could use a recursive solution:

```
function getMarkers(list) {
    return list.flatMap(o => 
         o._markers.concat(...getMarkers(o._childClusters || []))
    )
}

getMarkers(data)
```

Comment: Thank you, @thedude. Based in you code, I made my own fn.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the `_markers` is two layers deep. Do this: (`Top` is the parent object that's shown in the image you provided).

```
let clusters = [];
let markers = [];
for(i = 0; i < Top.length; i++){
   clusters.push(Top[i]._childClusters);
}
for(x = 0; x < clusters.length; x++){
  markers.push({x: clusters[x]._markers});
}
for(z = 0; z < markers.length; z++){
  // do something with the marker.
}
```

This is insanely inefficient, and if anyone can find a better way, please do so.